# How to install Tailwind 2.0 to an existing project (rails 6.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6, tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm trying to install Tailwind 2.0 to an existing project (rails 6.1) but get an error :

How to install Tailwind 2.0 on existing Rails project (6.1 and sprocket)

**In my gemfile I added :**

`gem "webpacker", github: "rails/webpacker", ref: 'b6c2180'`

**app/javascript/application.js**

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from '@rails/activestorage';
import '../utils/direct_uploads.js';
require("app/javascript/stylesheets/application.css")
Rails.start();
Turbolinks.start();
ActiveStorage.start();
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb :**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

**In the folder app/javascript/stylesheets/**

app/javascript/stylesheets/application.css

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

the file tailwind.config.js

And have run `rails webpacker:install` and `rails s` but get an error :

```
Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError - Webpacker can't find application.css in /Users/ben/code/Tioneb12/postgis/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
  "entrypoints": {
  }
}
```

**I'm trying :**

```
rails asset:clobber
yarn
rails asset:precompile
```

**and get another error :**

```
/Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory looking for modules in /Users/ben/node_modules
No description file found looking for modules in /Users/ben/code/Tioneb12/postgis/node_modules
using description file: /Users/ben/code/Tioneb12/postgis/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
using description file: /Users/ben/code/Tioneb12/postgis/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/babel-loader)
no extension /Users/ben/code/Tioneb12/postgis/node_modules/babel-loader doesn't exist
.js
/Users/ben/code/Tioneb12/postgis/node_modules/babel-loader.js doesn't exist
No description file found .json
/Users/ben/code/Tioneb12/postgis/node_modules/babel-loader.json doesn't exist no extension
/Users/ben/node_modules/babel-loader doesn't exist as directory
/Users/ben/code/Tioneb12/postgis/node_modules/babel-loader doesn't exist .js
/Users/ben/node_modules/babel-loader.js doesn't exist .json
/Users/ben/node_modules/babel-loader.json doesn't exist as directory
/Users/ben/node_modules/babel-loader doesn't exist
```

Comment: Did you first run `npm install`? "/Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory " this error is about missing npm packages.

Comment: I don't use npm but yarn. And node is installed and already up to date.
node -v => v14.15.4

Comment: Now I can compile without errors

Comment: You solved by running `yarn add` right?

Comment: I just solved the last error

Comment: have you run `yarn install`? does it ends successfully?

Comment: did you run the `webpacker:install` command? any reason to use webpacker's master branch from github instead of the gem from rubygems?

Comment: Yes, yarn install => already up to date

Comment: Yess, webpacker:install => Webpacker successfully installed

Comment: For Webpacker, I followed this post https://davidteren.medium.com/tailwindcss-2-0-with-rails-6-1-postcss-8-0-9645e235892d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the folder `tmp/cache/assets` worked for me ;)